# Regarding Stringstreams and clearing them

Tags: stringstream, word-count

I'm trying to write a program that counts how many words are in a file.

This code correctly counts the number of words, but why is it that if i remove the `iss.clear();` it will only count the number of words in the first line of the file?

```
stringstream iss;
while(getline(file, line))
{
    iss << line;
    while(getline(iss,word, ' '))
    {

        size++;
    }

    iss.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `while(getline(iss,word, ' '))` only gets the first line of the stringstream.  Try doing this:

```
int pos = 0;
stringstream iss;
while(getline(file, line))
{
     iss << line;
     while(getline(iss,word, ' '))
     {
          size++;
     }

     pos += line.length();
     iss.tellg(pos);
}
```

The last two lines positions the read pointer at the end of the new line you added, so the next getline will actually read the next line instead of the first one over and over again.